# How to change jquery knob value on mouse move?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jquery knob which values is getting updated on mouse scroll .i want it to be done on mouse move .

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a code like this:

```
var lastX;
var lastY;

$( "#container" ).mouseover(function() {
 $( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) { 
  var x = event.pageX;
  var y = event.pageY;
  /* here you add or subctract depens on compagin on lastX and lastY */
  /* at the end */
  var lastX = event.pageX;
  var lastY = event.pageY;
});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/49tuJ/)**

Comment: i tried but it is working on default mode i.e  mousescroll only

Answer (score 0):

You are probably searching for the `.mousemove()` function of jQuery.

Just make sure you apply it to the correct object.